# How to read a file without checking out in perforce

Tags: perl, perforce

I'm writing a syntax check tool to parse several files on different branches.
Is there a way for me to read the contents without checking out the file?
The tool is written in Perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
`p4 print //depot/path/to/file`;
```

(Usual requirements for running a p4 command apply -- make sure the p4 executable is in your PATH, make sure you're authenticated with `p4 login`, make sure you're connecting to the right server, etc.)

See `p4 help print` for more info on the `print` command -- you might find the `-q` and/or `-o` flags helpful depending on what exactly you need to do with the output.

Comment: Thanks for the command, Sam! I'm using the perl module P4, the api allows me to execute this p4 command like $p4->RunPrint("//depot/path/to/file");